# Modify argument separator with cmdargs

Tags: haskell, haskell-cmdargs

I'm using cmdargs and I need to pass several values after an optionnal argument.

I declared my `test` option to be a tuple of int :

```
data Options =
    Mode1   { input :: [FilePath]
            , test::(Int,Int)
            }

mode1 = 
  Mode1 { 
            input   = []  &= name "file" &= help "input file"    
          , test = (2,5)  &= explicit
        }
```

I can use my program with

```
./prog mode1 --test 5,6 --file "test_file.txt"
```

but I would like to have this syntax

```
./prog mode1 --test 5 6 --file "test_file.txt"
```

**Is it possible to modify the field separator to use spaces or another character instead of a comma?**

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It's the way command line arguments work. How about trying `--test 5 --test 6`?